# Is it true that more than half of the knowledge of the Atharva Veda was lost or went missing?

Tags: vedas, atharva-veda

I have often read that the Atharva Veda was a combined composition of both Atharvans and Bhrigus.
However the Atharva Veda consists of only the Atharvans part of the knowledge.

Is this true and described anywhere in later texts?

Edit:
Found a few blogs that describe this
https://sreenivasaraos.com/tag/bhrigu-angirasa-conflict/

http://hubpages.com/religion-philosophy/athravanavesta

Comment: Nope. it's preserved but not in INDIA.(AFAIK)

Comment: Not only atharva veda, many books from the hindus library. Because the king from afganistan, or may be from arab, attacked the hindus region, pakistan at that time many times. They destroyed temples and books. So no one knows how much they destroyed.

Comment: To be specific here , my question is about knowledge contained in the atharva veda, and not the actual text or book which has been interpreted by some

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible. It was ransacked and destroyed by an army of the Muslim Mamluk Dynasty under Bakhtiyar Khilji in c. 1197 CE.

So many temples of Hindu's and most famous library situated in Bihar named as Nalanda which contain ancient Hindu's Dharma Granth's (like veda's ) are destroyed and through them in fire as he is against Hinduism,  at that time so many books/granth's are not have duplicate copy and that's why as you said is possible.

But there is no any prof about veda's. You get details report about "Nalanda Agnikand" on google. As you mentioned Bhrigus, here are some details about [Bhrigu Rishi](http://www.indianetzone.com/29/bhrigu_rishi.htm).

Comment: To be specific here , my question is about knowledge contained in the atharva veda, and not the actual text or book which has been interpreted by some

Comment: Yes dear I am talking about the original Veda's and not a other books. I mention why because the actual content in atharva veda while converting from Sanskrit to other language it is found that there is some part which must be there but it is not there (all veda have a unique format of content and portion which are covered in it which conflict is atharva veda) and this is only incidence in which maximum Hindu granth are destroyed. so it possible the part which is not in atharva veda is destroyed there and not present in veda that we read.